# SQL Server 05: Inserting to new table and getting ID from an old and the newly created ID from new

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

I have 3 tables, one that has already been prepopulated with data and 2 that are brand new.

My first table (the prepopulated one) looks like this:

```
commentId, commentText, user_id, moderated, isDeleted, date_created
```

My second table looks like:

```
ActionID, moderated, isDeleted, reasonText, isReffered, isAllowed
```

and my third table looks like:

```
ID, ActionID, CommentID
```

What i'd like to be able to do is:

```
Insert into ActionTable (moderated, isDeleted)
Select moderated, isDeleted
From CommentTable
```

and grab the original commentID and newly created ActionID to be inserted into my third table ActionCommentLink

Cheers all.

Comment: You mention grabbing the original comment id which makes me think you want to update something yet your query only talks about an insert.  An insert is a new item, there is no original if you are inserting.  Did you mean to say an update?  An upsert?

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made myself clear.  What i wanted to do was insert details from an already existing table called comments into a new table called ActionTable.  I then wanted to insert into another new table called ActionCommentLink which would be the original CommentID (which wasn't being inserted anywhere) and ActionID which was a newly created ID on the ActionTable.  Once again i'm sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an auto-identity on `ActionID`?

Why do you need to have a `ActionCommentLink`? Based on the process you describe there is no n:m relation (yet).

If this is a one-time effort, the fastest way would be to temporarily add a `commentId` column to the `ActionTable` and populate it with the insert. If you don't actually need the `ActionCommentLink`, you are done already. Otherwise query the `ActionTable` to populate the Link, then remove the commentId from the `ActionTable`.

If you need to do this more than once, use a cursor and use the `@@Identity` function to query the last inserted `ActionID`

Comment: There is indeed an n:m relationship hence why the need for ActionCommentLink.  I'm beginning to think i'll have to create a temp column on the ActionTable, but was wondering if there was a cleverer way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use OUTPUT.  This is straight from the help file:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,
                           Name varchar(50),
                           ModifiedDate datetime);
INSERT Production.ScrapReason
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate
        INTO @MyTableVar
VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());

--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT NewScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate FROM @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate 
FROM Production.ScrapReason;
GO
```

Comment: From what I understand, output won't work because it deals with the inserted value.  Whereas I wanted the value from the original comment table rather than the ID from the ActionTable.  Unless i've misunderstood.

Comment: I did not see any reference to deleting anything in your original question.  If you want to deal with deleted table values it is easily done in a trigger as well but can also be done with the output clause like this: DELETE Sales.ShoppingCartItem
    OUTPUT DELETED.*;